# How to get ISOCurrencyCode from a ISOCountryCode in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the ISOCountryCode avaliable and now i want to derive the currencyCode of this country from the ISOCountryCode. How can i achieve that?

```
  NSString *countryCode =  < get from someother view>;     
  NSString *currencyCode = ?;
```

I receive this country code from some other view on runtime?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to use NSLocale. To retrieve the currency code from a specific country code:

```
NSString *countryCode = @"US";

NSDictionary *components = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countryCode forKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *localeIdent = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:components]; 
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdent] autorelease];
NSString *currencyCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```

You can also get it for the current locale, ie the user settings:

```
NSString *currencyCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```

Comment: My problem is like this. A user chooses a country from a list. And for this country I need to find the currency. And both the ways you have specified does not fulfill my requirement. I cannot hardcode anything. I have edited my question also a little bit. I hope that you understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

NSLocale encapsulates a rich set of domain-specific information, among others you have NSLocaleCurrencyCode:

```
 if let code = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) {
                print("\(code)")
            }
```