# How can i get the locale from currency names list

Tags: iphone, currency, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

i am making a currency selecting screen.for that i am displaying the list of currencies using the following code to create an array of currencies from which a tableview is populated

```
NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];
    for(NSString *country in countryArray)
    {
        //NSLog(@"%@",[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:country]);
        if([[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:country])
        {
        [countriesArray addObject:[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:country]];
        }
    }
```

.but i cant find a way to connect a currencies name and locale.ie if i select a currency name then i should be able to set the corresponding locale for currency display in other screens.How to find the locale from currencies list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same method from here with small modification..

[How to get ISOCurrencyCode from a ISOCountryCode in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433895/how-to-get-isocurrencycode-from-a-isocountrycode-in-iphone-sdk)

> NSString *currencyCode = @"ADP";
>
> NSDictionary *components = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:currencyCode forKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
>
> NSString *localeIdent = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:components];