# swift get currencycode from country code

Tags: swift2, nslocale

I find the accepted answer to get currencycode from country code in objective c here - [How to get ISOCurrencyCode from a ISOCountryCode in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433895/how-to-get-isocurrencycode-from-a-isocountrycode-in-iphone-sdk)

Can someone help with the swift code to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let components: [String: String] = [NSLocaleCountryCode: "CA"]

let identifier = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(components)

let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: identifier)

let currencyCode =  locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode)
print(currencyCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static func convertStringCurrencyToNumber(strCurrency:String, locale:String)->Double {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = locale
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    if let converted:Double = formatter.numberFromString(strCurrency)?.doubleValue {
        return converted
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Changing formatter.locale to formatter.currencyCode works as expected with the ISO 4127 Country and Currency code "USD".

Answer (score -3):

Use below this return type function to get country_code:-

```
 //MARK:- GET COUNTRY CODE
    func getCountryPhonceCode (_ country : String) -> String
    {


        let x : [String] = ["972", "IL",
                            "93" , "AF",
                            "355", "AL",
                            "213", "DZ",
                            "1"  , "AS",
                            "376", "AD",
                            "244", "AO",
                            "1"  , "AI",
                            "1"  , "AG",
                            "54" , "AR",
                            "374", "AM",
                            "297", "AW",
                            "61" , "AU",
                            "43" , "AT",
                            "994", "AZ",
                            "1"  , "BS",
                            "973", "BH",
                            "880", "BD",
                            "1"  , "BB",
                            "375", "BY",
                            "32" , "BE",
                            "501", "BZ",
                            "229", "BJ",
                            "1"  , "BM",
                            "975", "BT",
                            "387", "BA",
                            "267", "BW",
                            "55" , "BR",
                            "246", "IO",
                            "359", "BG",
                            "226", "BF",
                            "257", "BI",
                            "855", "KH",
                            "237", "CM",
                            "1"  , "CA",
                            "238", "CV",
                            "345", "KY",
                            "236", "CF",
                            "235", "TD",
                            "56", "CL",
                            "86", "CN",
                            "61", "CX",
                            "57", "CO",
                            "269", "KM",
                            "242", "CG",
                            "682", "CK",
                            "506", "CR",
                            "385", "HR",
                            "53" , "CU" ,
                            "537", "CY",
                            "420", "CZ",
                            "45" , "DK" ,
                            "253", "DJ",
                            "1"  , "DM",
                            "1"  , "DO",
                            "593", "EC",
                            "20" , "EG" ,
                            "503", "SV",
                            "240", "GQ",
                            "291", "ER",
                            "372", "EE",
                            "251", "ET",
                            "298", "FO",
                            "679", "FJ",
                            "358", "FI",
                            "33" , "FR",
                            "594", "GF",
                            "689", "PF",
                            "241", "GA",
                            "220", "GM",
                            "995", "GE",
                            "49" , "DE",
                            "233", "GH",
                            "350", "GI",
                            "30" , "GR",
                            "299", "GL",
                            "1"  , "GD",
                            "590", "GP",
                            "1"  , "GU",
                            "502", "GT",
                            "224", "GN",
                            "245", "GW",
                            "595", "GY",
                            "509", "HT",
                            "504", "HN",
                            "36" , "HU",
                            "354", "IS",
                            "91" , "IN",
                            "62" , "ID",
                            "964", "IQ",
                            "353", "IE",
                            "972", "IL",
                            "39" , "IT",
                            "1"  , "JM",
                            "81", "JP", "962", "JO", "77", "KZ",
                            "254", "KE", "686", "KI", "965", "KW", "996", "KG",
                            "371", "LV", "961", "LB", "266", "LS", "231", "LR",
                            "423", "LI", "370", "LT", "352", "LU", "261", "MG",
                            "265", "MW", "60", "MY", "960", "MV", "223", "ML",
                            "356", "MT", "692", "MH", "596", "MQ", "222", "MR",
                            "230", "MU", "262", "YT", "52","MX", "377", "MC",
                            "976", "MN", "382", "ME", "1", "MS", "212", "MA",
                            "95", "MM", "264", "NA", "674", "NR", "977", "NP",
                            "31", "NL", "599", "AN", "687", "NC", "64", "NZ",
                            "505", "NI", "227", "NE", "234", "NG", "683", "NU",
                            "672", "NF", "1", "MP", "47", "NO", "968", "OM",
                            "92", "PK", "680", "PW", "507", "PA", "675", "PG",
                            "595", "PY", "51", "PE", "63", "PH", "48", "PL",
                            "351", "PT", "1", "PR", "974", "QA", "40", "RO",
                            "250", "RW", "685", "WS", "378", "SM", "966", "SA",
                            "221", "SN", "381", "RS", "248", "SC", "232", "SL",
                            "65", "SG", "421", "SK", "386", "SI", "677", "SB",
                            "27", "ZA", "500", "GS", "34", "ES", "94", "LK",
                            "249", "SD", "597", "SR", "268", "SZ", "46", "SE",
                            "41", "CH", "992", "TJ", "66", "TH", "228", "TG",
                            "690", "TK", "676", "TO", "1", "TT", "216", "TN",
                            "90", "TR", "993", "TM", "1", "TC", "688", "TV",
                            "256", "UG", "380", "UA", "971", "AE", "44", "GB",
                            "1", "US", "598", "UY", "998", "UZ", "678", "VU",
                            "681", "WF", "967", "YE", "260", "ZM", "263", "ZW",
                            "591", "BO", "673", "BN", "61", "CC", "243", "CD",
                            "225", "CI", "500", "FK", "44", "GG", "379", "VA",
                            "852", "HK", "98", "IR", "44", "IM", "44", "JE",
                            "850", "KP", "82", "KR", "856", "LA", "218", "LY",
                            "853", "MO", "389", "MK", "691", "FM", "373", "MD",
                            "258", "MZ", "970", "PS", "872", "PN", "262", "RE",
                            "7", "RU", "590", "BL", "290", "SH", "1", "KN",
                            "1", "LC", "590", "MF", "508", "PM", "1", "VC",
                            "239", "ST", "252", "SO", "47", "SJ",
                            "963","SY",
                            "886",
                            "TW", "255",
                            "TZ", "670",
                            "TL","58",
                            "VE","84",
                            "VN",
                            "284", "VG",
                            "340", "VI",
                            "678","VU",
                            "681","WF",
                            "685","WS",
                            "967","YE",
                            "262","YT",
                            "27","ZA",
                            "260","ZM",
                            "263","ZW"]
        var keys = [String]()
        var values = [String]()
        let whitespace = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

        //let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespace)
        for i in x {
            // range will be nil if no whitespace is found
            if  (i.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespace) != nil) {
                values.append(i)
            }
            else {
                keys.append(i)
            }
        }


        let countryCodeListDict = NSDictionary(objects: values as [String], forKeys: keys as [String] as [NSCopying])
        if let t: AnyObject = (countryCodeListDict as? [String : AnyObject])? [country] {
            return countryCodeListDict[country] as! String
        } else
        {
            return ""
        }

    }
```